# How to make String as a condition in java

Tags: java

Is there any way to make a string as a condtion in java.

Sample is shown below

```
class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        B b = new B(10, 20);
        b.setCondition("val1>val2");
    }
}

class B {
    int val1 = 0;
    int val2 = 0;

    public B(int v1, int v2) {
        val1 = v1;
        val2 = v2;
    }

    public void setCondition(String condition){
   //the string should be evaluated as conditon like below.
     if(condition) ->  if(val1>val2)

   }
}
```

Is this is possibility in java.
Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not possible, `if` should contain a statement that'll be evaluated to `true` or `false`, not a String.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an eval() function in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own parser, since Java code needs to be compiled. There is no `evaluate()` method, such as PHP or other scripting languages provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is inside an `if` statement should evaluate to a `boolean`, in other words to `true` or `false`.

You want to be able to pass arbitrary conditions in `String` form, then you are gonna have to define a parser for your `String`s.

If you really need to do this, which I kinda doubt for the record, consider defining a class that takes a `String` as constructor argument, two integer values to be evaluated and returns a `boolean`. Something like:

```
class Evaluator{
  public Evaluator(String condition){
    // parse condition
  }
  public boolean evaluate(int v1, int v2){ 
    // return true if condition is satisfied, false otherwise
  }
}
```